# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type: class com.codahale.metrics.Timer$Context to put in async map

Tags: vert.x

I have created a vertx AsyncMap< Long, Context > where I store dropwizard timer for a specific jobId. But when I put any value to map I am getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type: class com.codahale.metrics.Timer$Context to put in async map" error.

Code for map initialization: 
    `vertxService.getVertx().sharedData().<Long,Context>getClusterWideMap("mapName", ar -> {
            if(ar.succeeded()){
                tempAsyncMap = ar.result();
            }else{
                log.error("Not able to get cluster wide map with name due to {}:",ar.cause());
            }
        });`

code for putting timer to map: 
`tempAsyncMap.put(jobId, jobWaitTimer.time(), completionHandler -> {});`

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an object of any type in a cluster-wide map. It must be one of the base JDK types (`String`, `Integer`, ... etc), the base Vert.x types (`Buffer`, `JsonObject`, `JsonArray`). Otherwise the type must implement `ClusterSerializable`.

But given the type of value you want to share, I would recommend to use a `LocalMap`, not a cluster-wide map. For this one, custom objects must implement `Shareable`.